# Parallel Processing in QT

Tags: qt

How is parallel processing achieved in Qt. Suppose i need to call two functions which performs serial communication with multiple serial devices connected.

Func_A() handles serial communication with Device 1 and Func_B() handles serial communication with Device 2 and so on, but both needs to be communicated in parallel and not sequential .

The motive is to communicate with multiple devices connected through serial/Ethernet at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

If you use non-blocking functions for communication, you can handle all your serial communication within the same thread with no issue.
Each device (QSerialPort) will emit a signal (i.e. call a function) when data is received. From there you can decode this data in the corresponding slots. Sending data can be triggered either by UI events, by timers, and by any other event.
This is the simplest.

If you really do heavy computations when encoding/decoding communication, you can create several QThread, one to handle each device. And then, you can connect signals between your different threads with Qt::QueuedConnection (automatic) to avoid the need for mutex or other inter-thread synchronization logic.